how to capture user's text input with python modules
i am working on a project where it detects where if you press "(" it closes it automatically
the same thing for "[" and "{"
but the point is it detects the keyboard button "{" or "["
not the character
that means if a friend have a different way to type "[" it wont work because the program is used to detect the "altgr+(" sequence
and that might effect on different languages keyboards
because you dont want to activate a hotkey accidentally when you pressed a button in the same position but in another language (so you dont need that option)
is there a way to detect the "[" character no matters how the user get it? in python
i tired every python module that i can access "keyboard" "pynput" "pyKey"...

Yes, you detected the character, not the keyboard button.

My guess is the console isn't the right tool for whatever you're trying to do, but I can't be sure...what's the use case exactly?
